# Bash command to control vi

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm still a little new to bash scripting. There is a command my class uses and it auto opens vi. I only know the alias but not the file nor the location as it is a programs command (specifically IBMs. CLearCase command cleartool edcs) However, I want bash to open the file, enter commands into vi to edit the file, and then save said file. Is there a way to do this? I know how to do sed command but idk if that will work in this situation. Thank you!

Comment: You want `bash` to open which file? What do you want to write into the file? I suspect a simple `echo xyz >> file` should do what you want. But more details needed.

Comment: @VarunM Well that's the problem. We are using a program called IBM ClearCase. I want to edit the configuration spec. IBM offers an alias for that, but idk what the specific file name is. All I know is when I enter the command cleartool edcs, it opens the config spec w/ vi. Otherwise I would use the echo command like I have in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `ex` instead of `vi` if you want automation. vi is build on top of ex, but you can easily pass a script of commands to ex.

An example:

```
$ cat <<END >file
one
two
three
END

$ ex file <<'COMMANDS'
1i
zero
.
1,$s/[aieou]/\U&/g
wq
COMMANDS

$ cat file
zErO
OnE
twO
thrEE
```

Comment: The only problem is I use a command provided by ClearCase as I can't find the config spec file anywhere. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_edcs.htm